# jQuery Filter Show Data Attribute Any or All

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, wildcard

I've some drop downs with which a user can `filter()` the divs below. The buttons reference three separate data attributes. When a button is clicked, the value is added into an array, I then filter the content based on the values in those arrays. While I just had two drop downs I ran through four scenarios to test whether the array was empty: if it was empty I just tested for existence of the data-attribute, if there was a value then I used it for filtering.

With the addition of a third filter I have (I think) 9 possible scenarios to test for and wonder if there's a better way to do this.

For example, when I just had two filters my arrays might look like:

```
["united-kingdom", "ireland"] //country
[] //type

var results = $(".collaborator[data-country][data-collaborator_type][data-interest]").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if( countryArr.length !== 0 && collaborator_typeArr.length !== 0 ) {
        return countryArr.includes($this.attr("data-country")) && collaborator_typeArr.includes($this.attr("data-collaborator_type"));

    } else if( countryArr.length === 0 && collaborator_typeArr.length === 0 ) {
        return $this.attr('data-country') && $this.attr('data-collaborator_type');

    } else if( countryArr.length === 0 ) {
        console.log('any country');
        return $this.attr('data-country') && collaborator_typeArr.includes($this.attr("data-collaborator_type"));

    } else if( collaborator_typeArr.length === 0 ) {
        console.log('any type');
        return countryArr.includes($this.attr("data-country")) && $this.attr('data-collaborator_type');
    }
});

$('section.collaborator').slideUp('fast');
results.slideDown('fast');
```

Which would return results in United Kingdom and Ireland of any type.

What I can't figure out is a better way to achieve the 'any' value. Is there a way that I can test for 'any' or a wildcard value, instead of checking to see if the array is empty.

What if my arrays looked like

```
["united-kingdom", "ireland"] //country
["*"] //type
```

How might I filter to return all for the wildcard filter?

Comment: Could you show the relevant "*[mcve]*" HTML, so that we can reproduce your problem easily? I can't help but think, looking at your posted jQuery, that there must be a simpler solution but without the HTML - and perhaps CSS - it's something of a difficult theoretical exercise.

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas - I've made a fiddle (my first): https://jsfiddle.net/nugerama/4yychd87/

Comment: Are you required to stick with the same HTML, or can that be amended? I'm thinking about, specifically, changing some of the `data-*` attributes (or perhaps adding some to make this easier, is that allowed by your use-case or project requirements?

Comment: Oh yeah, @DavidThomas - this is all my code so please, make any recommendations and I'll work them in.

Answer (score 0):

Because my own scripting style leads me to making something that's moderately extensible without having to append cases – however simple or complex those cases may be to add – I changed the approach taken in the script.

I also added a couple of components to your HTML, though these can be removed as you require.

That said, the approach I've taken is below, I've tried to explain the code fully in comments (even those parts present in the original, for the benefit of those that may view the question and answers in the future):

```
// delegating the event handler to the '#network-filters'
// element, binding the anonymous function of the on()
// method to act as the 'click' event-handler for the
// click events on those elements contained within that
// match the 'a.filter' selector:
$('#network-filters').on('click', 'a.filter', function(event) {

  // preventing the default action of the <a> elements,
  // preventing the page from following the clicked links:
  event.preventDefault();

  // using the 'let' statement to declare variables, this is
  // possible in ES6-supporting browsers, for older browsers
  // you may have to use 'var' instead (in this situation
  // they're interchangeable).

  // caching the clicked element:
  let clicked = $(this),

    // finding the elements that contain the elements to
    // be filtered (I added the '#results' element):
    results = $('#results .collaborator');

  // toggling the 'toggled' class, to turn it 'on' or 'off'
  // on the clicked <a>, and removing it from the sibling
  // elements:
  clicked.toggleClass('toggled').siblings().removeClass('toggled');

  // caching '.dropdown' elements:
  let dropdowns = $('#network-filters .dropdown'),

  // declaring 'empty' variables for use within
  // the up-coming 'Array.prototype.map()' call:
    filter,
    active,
    filterValue,

  // here we convert the dropdowns jQuery collection into
  // a native JavaScript Array using get(), and then we
  // iterate over that Array using Array.prototype.map():
    selector = dropdowns.get().map(function(dropdown) {
      // 'dropdown' a reference to the current element
      // in the Array of elements over which we're
      // iterating.

      // assigning values to the declared 'empty' variables:
        // here we retrieve the value of the 'data-tax'
        // custom attribute, using the Element.dataset API:
      filter = dropdown.dataset.tax;

        // here we retrieve the element matching the supplied
        // CSS selector contained within the current
        // dropdown element, querySelector returns the first
        // or no matching elements:
      active = dropdown.querySelector('a.filter.toggled');

        // if we have an 'active' element we pass the value
        // of its 'data-filter' attribute to the variable,
        // otherwise we return false:
      filterValue = active ? active.dataset.filter : false;

      // if there was an active element:
      if (active) {
        // we construct a selector to return to the Array
        // we're creating via Array.prototype.map(), that
        // selector takes the form of:
          // 'data-' plus the attribute-value of the
          // 'data-tax' attribute, followed by either an
          // empty string (if the filterValue is exactly
          // equal to 'any') or a string containing '='
          // follwed by the found filterValue; this is
          // all then followed by a ']' character to
          // close the formed attribute-selector:
        return '[data-' + filter + (filterValue === 'any' ? '' : '=' + filterValue) + ']';

      // otherwise:
      } else {
        // we simply return false, if there was no active
        // element:
        return false;
      }

    // we then use Array.prototype.filter(Boolean) to retain
    // only those true/truthy values in the Array
    }).filter(Boolean)

    // and join all array-elements together with an empty string:
    .join('');

  // those results (the '#results .collaborator' elements) are
  // then filtered; those that do not match the created selector
  // are hidden via the slideUp() method:
  results.not(selector).slideUp();

  // then we filter the results array to find those that
  // are hidden (.not(':visible') - using the ':visible'
  // jQuery/Sizzle custom selector) which match the
  // formed selector and apply slideDown() to those
  // elements; this is simply to avoid sliding elements
  // both up and down if they're already visible:
  results.not(':visible').filter(selector).slideDown();

  // here we use a comparison to discover whether or not
  // we have any results; if the number of results elements
  // filtered by the selector is greater than 0, we return
  // true (because we have found some results), otherwise
  // we return false (because there were no matching results):
  let resultsAvailable = results.filter(selector).length > 0;

  // here we find the element (added by me to your HTML) which
  // conveys the 'result-state', and toggle the 'noResult'
  // class using the switch, in which we invert the
  // resultsAvailble variable, so that the class is added if
  // there are no results available, and removed if there are
  // results available (its default state is to be hidden,
  // and shown only if there are no results, this is in the CSS):
  $('#results .resultState').toggleClass('noResult', !resultsAvailable);

});
```

The above JavaScript is coupled with the following HTML:

```
<div id="network-filters">
  <div class="dropdown" data-tax="country">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="filter all" data-filter="any">Show All</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="ireland">Ireland</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a>

      <!-- the following two <a> elements are added to show how
           easily this approach can be extended; note that there
           is no matching element for the 'Scotland' <a>, to
           demonstrate that the script still works despite that -->
      <a class="filter" data-filter="wales">Wales</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="scotland">Scotland</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" data-tax="collaborator">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="filter all" data-filter="any">Show All</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="artist">Artist</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="partner">Partner</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- the '#results' element was added to logically group the
     elements to be searched together -->
<div id="results">

  <!-- the 'resultState' element was added to visibly inform
       the user that the search was conducted and the lack of
       results is deliberate, rather than the result of a
       broken script -->
  <div class="resultState">No results available for that choice.</div>
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="ireland" data-collaborator="artist">
    <ul>
      <li>country = ireland</li>
      <li>type = artist</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="united-kingdom" data-collaborator="partner">
    <ul>
      <li>country = united-kingdom</li>
      <li>type = partner</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- the following element was effectively cloned 
       from the same format as the other elements, 
       and dropped in justas a demonstration of how 
       easily this approach can be extended -->
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="wales" data-collaborator="partner">
    <ul>
      <li>country = wales</li>
      <li>type = partner</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#network-filters').on('click', 'a.filter', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let clicked = $(this),
    results = $('#results .collaborator');

  clicked.toggleClass('toggled').siblings().removeClass('toggled');

  let dropdowns = $('#network-filters .dropdown'),
    filter,
    active,
    filterValue,
    selector = dropdowns.get().map(function(dropdown) {
      filter = dropdown.dataset.tax;
      active = dropdown.querySelector('a.filter.toggled');
      filterValue = active ? active.dataset.filter : false;

      if (active) {
        return '[data-' + filter + (filterValue === 'any' ? '' : '=' + filterValue) + ']';
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }).filter(Boolean).join('');

  results.not(selector).slideUp();
  results.not(':visible').filter(selector).slideDown();

  let resultsAvailable = results.filter(selector).length > 0;

  $('#results .resultState').toggleClass('noResult', !resultsAvailable);

});
```

```css
/* SCSS from JS Fiddle demo (https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5c08shbn/1/)
compiled to CSS via 'http://www.sassmeister.com/' */

.dropdown {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.dropdown a {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
.dropdown a.toggled {
  /* I just prefer the brighter colour */
  background-color: limegreen;
}
.collaborator {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: white;
}
.resultState {
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.resultState.noResult {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="network-filters">
  <div class="dropdown" data-tax="country">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="filter all" data-filter="any">Show All</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="ireland">Ireland</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="united-kingdom">United Kingdom</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="wales">Wales</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="scotland">Scotland</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown" data-tax="collaborator">
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="filter all" data-filter="any">Show All</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="artist">Artist</a>
      <a class="filter" data-filter="partner">Partner</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <div class="resultState">No results available for that choice.</div>
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="ireland" data-collaborator="artist">
    <ul>
      <li>country = ireland</li>
      <li>type = artist</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="united-kingdom" data-collaborator="partner">
    <ul>
      <li>country = united-kingdom</li>
      <li>type = partner</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collaborator" data-country="wales" data-collaborator="partner">
    <ul>
      <li>country = wales</li>
      <li>type = partner</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5c08shbn/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [Conditional (ternary) operator: `assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/conditional_operator).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
  - [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).
  - [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).
  - [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: Wow, thanks @David Thomas. I'm going to work through your code now. First though, I've had a quick look at the fiddle and can see that it's not possible to select multiple filter values. It's a requirement of the brief to be able to select, for example: 'partner' in 'united kingdom' or 'ireland'. Apologies if I didn't make that clear if you've allowed for that in your example and I've missed it.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; as to your observation: no, sadly I haven't made that possible I may have misunderstood a couple of aspects of your question. If you could take a look and let me know if I've left out anything else you require I'll take another look to make it work :)

Comment: Amazing, thanks @David Thomas. I have had a look through and adjusted your code to see what would happen if I didn't un-toggle adjacent filter buttons on click but I see it's not that simple : o. This is why I found myself going down the route of adding and removing from arrays for each separate taxonomy and then combining them at the end. For example, on your fiddle if I select 'show all' for country and 'artist' and 'partner' for role then I should be left with all of the results (1 artist and 2 partners in 'any' country). Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, that's perfectly understandable (or at least I think I clearly understand it...). Give me a little while, though it might be a couple of hours depending on other tasks, to update things a little :)

Comment: Just to clarify, would the same be true of the countries? Should you be able to select Ireland and United Kingdom *and* partner and artist?

Comment: Yes, that's right David. Bearing in mind also that I'm about to add a third filter group (interests) to this, which is what promoted me to seek out a better solution. There will be three filter fields (automatically populated by the WordPress taxonomies) and a user will be able to select any number of each one, e.g.: **in** UK **or** Ireland **and** Partner **or** Artist. The button toggling that I was doing originally was to toggle the ALL button **OFF** if any of the other buttons were selected and to toggle all other buttons (in that group) **OFF** if the all button was selected.